# GraphQL with Sequelize returns null on a hasOne relation

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js

I defined Cars, Brands, and Images. Cars return all images but it returns Brand as null. (I don't show the definition of Images because it is working just fine, unlike Brand)
Each car has only one brand and multiple images so I defined as follows:

```
 Cars.associate = models => {
    Cars.hasOne(models.brands, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'id',
        allowNull: false
      },
      sourceKey: 'brand_id',
      required : true
    }),
    Cars.hasMany(models.car_images, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'car_id',
        allowNull: false
      },
      onDelete: "cascade"
    })
  };
```

Then I defined Brands and I associated to Cars:

```
 CarBrands.associate = models => {
    CarBrands.belongsTo(models.cars, {
      sourceKey: 'id',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'id',
      }
    });
```

The SQL is built fine, all the information is returned yet when I query the GraphQL brand returns always null:

```
SELECT `cars`.`id`, `cars`.`user_id`, `cars`.`title`, `cars`.`created_at`, `cars`.`updated_at`, `brand`.`id` AS `brand.id`, `brand`.`name` AS `brand.name`, `brand`.`status` AS `brand.status`, `car_images`.`id` AS `car_images.id`, `car_images`.`car_id` AS `car_images.car_id`, `car_images`.`image` AS `car_images.image`, `car_images`.`created_at` AS `car_images.created_at`, `car_images`.`updated_at` AS `car_images.updated_at` FROM `cars` AS `cars` LEFT OUTER JOIN `brands` AS `brand` ON `cars`.`brand_id` = `brand`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `car_images` AS `car_images` ON `cars`.`id` = `car_images`.`car_id`;
```

When I query:

```
brand_name {
      name
    }
```

It returns:

```
   "brand_name": null
```

The definitions are as follows:

Cars.js

```
export const typeDef = `
    type Cars {
        user_id: Int!,
        title: String!,
        brand_id: Int!,
        brand_name: [CarBrands],
        car_images: [CarImages]
    }
`;

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        async getAllCars (root, args, { models }) {
            return models.cars.findAll({
                include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]
            })
        },
    }
};
```

CarBrands.js

```
export const typeDef = `
    type CarBrands {
        id: Int!,
        name: String,
        status: Int
    }
`;
```

cars.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Cars = sequelize.define('cars', {
    'id': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      comment: "null",
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    'user_id': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      comment: "null"
    }
  }, {
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    tableName: 'cars',
    underscored: true
  });
  Cars.associate = models => {
    Cars.hasOne(models.brands, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'id',
        allowNull: false
      },
      sourceKey: 'brand_id',
      required : true
    }),
 
    Cars.hasMany(models.car_images, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'car_id',
        allowNull: false
      },
      onDelete: "cascade"
    })
  };
  return Cars;
};
```

brands.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const CarBrands = sequelize.define('brands', {
    'id': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      comment: "null",
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    'name': {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true,
      comment: "null"
    },
    'status': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(3),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1',
      comment: "null"
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'brands'
  });
  CarBrands.associate = models => {
    CarBrands.belongsTo(models.cars, {
      sourceKey: 'id',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'id',
      }
    });
  };
  return CarBrands;
};
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear how the field `brand_name` relates to the models you've shown. You should show the relevant parts of your schema, including both the relevant type definitions and relevant resolver code.

Comment: @DanielRearden thank you. I just added all the code. Thanks for the suggestion.